# Linux Shell - Grep command

Tags: linux, shell, command-line, grep, command

I'm having a problem using grep with these options: `\{n\}` , `\{n,\}` and `\{n,m\}` . I have a file named "new" with this lines:

```
aaaa
aaa
aa
a
```

When i use `grep 'a\{1\}' new` i get this output:

```
aaaa
aaa
aa
a
```

So, basically, this command will show me the lines that include 1, or more, consecutive occurrences of the character "a" right?

Also, `grep 'a\{1,\} new` will do the same thing as `grep 'a\{1\}' new` ? Because i get the same output for both.

The last one, `\{n,m\}` , i cant really understand what it does.

I would really appreciate if anyone could help me out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From `man grep`:

```
   Repetition
       A regular expression may be  followed  by  one  of  several  repetition
       operators:
       ?      The preceding item is optional and matched at most once.
       *      The preceding item will be matched zero or more times.
       +      The preceding item will be matched one or more times.
       {n}    The preceding item is matched exactly n times.
       {n,}   The preceding item is matched n or more times.
       {n,m}  The  preceding  item  is  matched at least n times, but not more
              than m times.
```

That example `grep 'a\{2,3\}' new` matches also the line with `aaaa` because of the first three (or 2) `a`. The rest of the line isn't important.

If you want that really only 2 or 3 consecutive `a` are matched, you could use the `-o` flag. But be aware that this would output `aa` and `aaa` from a line with `aaaaa`. To avoid this you have to use additional information, like in the example line breakings `^` and `$`.

Btw. I would suggest to use the `-E` flag (or `egrep` which is the same) so you have extended regex support. You don't have to escape the brackets then.

For input

```
aaaaa
aaaa
aaa
aa
a
```

a call of `grep -o -E '^a{2,3}$'` will give the output:

```
aaa
aa
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Excelent answer!

Comment: Thanks for the extra info. I was actually searching for info about grep -E! Thanks you so much!

Answer (score 2):

`grep 'a\{n,m\}' new` means grepping at least n number of `a` and at most m number of `a` from new.
For example, `grep 'a\{2,3\}' new` will output

```
aaaa
aaa
aa
```

the last line doesnot match because it only has ONE `a`.
For `a{n,\}'` , omitting `m` means any number larger than or equal to `n`.

Comment: @Exsound It's normal, because `aaaa` indeed contains 1 or 2 or 3 `a`s.Thus it's printed. As a matter of fact, for `a\{1,3\}`, any line containing just ONE `a` will be printed.